# Does my Polish work permit let me travel through the EU?

Tags: visas, schengen, work, poland

I have one year Polish work permit visa, valid for one year.

Can I go to other European countries (such as Germany, Belgium, Portugal, France) because of the work permit visa issued by Poland?

Comment: what kind of permit is it? is it the national visa with permission to work or a residence permit?

Comment: "Work permit visa" doesn't sound like official terminology, so it is a bit unclear exactly what it is you have. Can you post a picture of it with your personal information blotted out?

Comment: @ThisIsMyName it shouldn't matter. National visas and residence permits have the same effect infer the Schengen codes.

Comment: @phoog tell this to an Indian friend of mine who was employed at Polish university as a researcher and couldn't leave Poland, coz his visa was just a national Polish visa with a permission to work.

Comment: @ThisIsMyName who told your friend he couldn't leave Poland?  (My previous comment should have said "under" rather than "infer.")

Comment: @phoog stuff at the university that handled his application and local commune that issued the work permit.

Comment: @ThisIsMyName perhaps they were unfamiliar with the Schengen codes, especially [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399) Article 6(1)(b) (which requires "possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001, **except where they hold a valid residence permit or a valid long-stay visa**," emphasis added), or perhaps there were other considerations such as an SIS alert (Art. 6(1)(d)) or a "threat to public interests" alert from another Schengen state (Art. 6(1)(e)).

Comment: @phoog or the situation was before Poland entering Schengen.

Comment: @Krizz that is possible, but if so it was over a decade ago.  Poland joined in 2007.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a valid resident permit for a Schengen country you are free to travel to other Schengen countries.

> If your visa is from a "Schengen area" country, it automatically
>   allows you to travel to the other Schengen countries as well.

[europa.eu - Travel documents for non-EU nationals](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm)

Comment: However, I think some member states issue "work permits" separately from "residence permits", and in that case a work permit itself does not count as a residence permit.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Would the quote from europa.eu still include work permits as they will have needed a visa to get the work permit?

Comment: The problem would be someone with a work permit whose presence is authorized by a short-stay visa or under the Annex II exemption, because they would be more likely to run afoul of the 90/180 rule. @HenningMakholm is that what you were thinking of, or was it something else?